# How to use asn1_create_element for nested schemes?

Tags: c, asn.1

libtasn1 library provides functions for creating encoded data. Particulary asn1_create_element() function is used for creating structures before encoding. Nested definitions are failing.

Libtasn1 library provides test examples, the one I am interested pertains to encoding.
**Test_encoding.asn**

```
TEST_TREE { }

DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=

BEGIN

Koko ::= SEQUENCE {
   seqint SEQUENCE OF INTEGER,
   int INTEGER,
   a      [1] OCTET STRING,
   b      [10] OCTET STRING,
   c      [100] OCTET STRING,
   exp    [3] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
   str OCTET STRING
}
```

This is a simple scheme with straight forward data types.

The **Test_encoding.c** further fills these structures using:

```
 result = asn1_create_element (definitions, "TEST_TREE.Koko", &asn1_element);
...
result = asn1_write_value (asn1_element, "seqint", "NEW", 1);
...
result = asn1_write_value (asn1_element, "int", "\x0f\xff\x01", 3);
```

My scheme is nested:

```
MYP7B { }

DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::= 

BEGIN

Encoder ::= SEQUENCE {
    signedData1     OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
    object1         XmlInfo
}

XmlInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    serialno        INTEGER,
    checksum1       INTEGER,
    digest1         OCTET STRING,
    data1           OCTET STRING
}
```

my main.c has thus:

```
result = asn1_create_element (definitions, "MYP7B.Encoder", &asn1_element);
...
result = asn1_create_element (definitions, "MYP7B.Encoder.XmlInfo", &asn1_element);
```

I get the following error:

```
asn1_create_element(): LIBTASN1 ERROR: ELEMENT_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 2nd parameter "MYP7B.Encoder.XmlInfo" by "MYP7B.XmlInfo", as it is not nested from the point of view of the ASN1 definition.